# How to stop the overloaded new() from getting invoked from Ostream in C++ / Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, new-operator, ostream

How can I fix the crash here? How to avoid new() operator while logging in a file?

I am writing a memory troubleshoot debugger. This will write on to a file every 10 seconds about - " The free blocks available and will check the signature of the memory blocks for buffer overflow run." Here is my design -

[image]

Here is the code that tries do the monitoring.I see a crash after sometime. Also, the Ostream is calling - new and the redundant data is captured in the file. I won't mind to use C type of calls also.

```html
/** Headers needed for the tool **/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include  <execinfo.h>
#include  <cxxabi.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

/** timer check **/
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
/** timer checks ends here **/


/*** USE CASE HEADERS ***/
#include "memOperation.h"
#include  "DumpMemory.h"
/*** USE CASE HEADERS ENDS ***/


/** Buffer for adding Pattern - Signature **/
#define BUFFER (4)

/*** Array Assume-- map of pointers and size  *********/
struct pointerBlkSizeInfo
{
 unsigned long int m_PointerAddress;
 unsigned long int m_blkSize;
};


/*** String for File Name path ***/
const char *FileName = "/export/home/joshis1/DBG_REC.log";

/*** DUMP Corrupted Memory details **/
const char *FileCorruptDetails = "/export/home/joshis1/DBG_CORRUPT.log";

/**** Maintain array of pointerBlkSizeInfo **/
#define MONITOR_MEM_SIZE  (1024)
/**** Map created **************************/
pointerBlkSizeInfo ptrSizeMap[MONITOR_MEM_SIZE];

/*** Prototype *********/
static void startMonitorMem();
/*****************Prototype ends here **/


/**********Prints the caller needs rdynamic***********************/
static void printCaller( void )
{
 void *array[ 50 ];
 int size = backtrace( array, 50 );
 char **messages = backtrace_symbols( array, size );

 std::ofstream dumpfile;
 dumpfile.open(FileName);

 /* skip first and second stack frame (points here) */
 for ( int frame = 0; frame < size  && messages != NULL; ++frame )
 {
  char *mangled_name = 0, *offset_begin = 0, *offset_end = 0;

  /* find parantheses and +address offset surrounding mangled name */
  for ( char *msg = messages[frame]; *msg; ++msg )
  {
   if ( *msg == '(' )
   {
    mangled_name = msg;
   }
   else if ( *msg == '+' )
   {
    offset_begin = msg;
   }
   else if ( *msg == ')' )
   {
    offset_end = msg;
    break;
   }
  }

  /* if the line could be processed, attempt to demangle the symbol */
  if ( mangled_name && offset_begin && offset_end &&
    mangled_name < offset_begin )
  {
   *mangled_name++ = '\0';
   *offset_begin++ = '\0';
   *offset_end++ = '\0';

   int status;
   char * real_name = abi::__cxa_demangle(mangled_name, 0, 0, &status);

   /* if demangling is successful, output the demangled function name */
   if ( status == 0 )
   {
    dumpfile<< "demangled name"<<real_name<<std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
    dumpfile<<"mangled name"<< real_name <<std::endl;
   }
   free( real_name );
  }
 }
 free( messages );

 struct mallinfo freeblockAvailable;

 freeblockAvailable = mallinfo();

 dumpfile<<"Available free space in bytes = "<<freeblockAvailable.fordblks;

 dumpfile.close();
}

/** Overloaded new Operator **/
void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
 unsigned int index = 0;

 char buff[4] = "ACE";

 void *mem = std::malloc(sz + BUFFER );
 std::cout<<"Strcpy Started"<<std::endl;
 strncpy((char *)((unsigned long int )mem + sz),buff,4);
 std::cout<<"Strcpy done"<<std::endl;
 printCaller();

 for(index = 0; index <= MONITOR_MEM_SIZE; index++ )
 {
  if( ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress == 0 )
  {
   ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress =  ( unsigned long int)mem;
   ptrSizeMap[index].m_blkSize = sz;
   break;
  }
 }

 if(index  > MONITOR_MEM_SIZE )
 {
  std::cout<<"MemoryTool..MapSize Increase"<<std::endl;
 }

 return mem;
}

/** Overloaded free Operator **/
void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
 std::free(ptr);

 for(unsigned int index = 0; index <= MONITOR_MEM_SIZE; index++ )
 {
  if( ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress == (unsigned long int)ptr )
  {
   ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress =  0;
   ptrSizeMap[index].m_blkSize = 0;
   break;
  }
 }
}


/**************Memory Monitor Routine--Every 10 seconds executes *******************************/
void monitorMem (int temp)
{
 struct itimerval tout_val;

 std::ofstream corruptMemFile;
 corruptMemFile.open(FileName);

 std::cout<<"Monitoring Memory!!!"<<std::endl;
 tout_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
 tout_val.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
 tout_val.it_value.tv_sec = 10; /* 10 seconds timer */
 tout_val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

 /**** check if the memory buffer overflow occurred or not **/

 for(unsigned int index = 0; index <= MONITOR_MEM_SIZE; index++ )
 {
  if (ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress != 0 )
  {
   const char *temp = (char *) (ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress + ptrSizeMap[index].m_blkSize);

   if(strncmp(temp,"ACE",3) == 0 )
   {
    /** Matched **/
   }
   else
   {
    /** Un -Matched ***/
    std::cout<<"Shreyas..the memory is corrupted";
    corruptMemFile<<"Pointer corrupted = "<<ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress<<" Size = "<<ptrSizeMap[index].m_blkSize;

   }
  }

 }

 corruptMemFile.close();
 signal(SIGALRM,monitorMem);
 setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tout_val,0);

}

/*** Start Monitoring the Mem -- Timer Initialization ***/
static void startMonitorMem()
{
 /** initialize the memory lookup map to zero **/
 memset(&ptrSizeMap,0,sizeof(pointerBlkSizeInfo)*MONITOR_MEM_SIZE);

 struct itimerval tout_val;
 tout_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
 tout_val.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
 tout_val.it_value.tv_sec = 10; /* 10 seconds timer */
 tout_val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
 setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tout_val,0);
 signal(SIGALRM,monitorMem); /* set the Alarm signal capture */
}



/********************Main routine ************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 /** Install the memory monitoring now **/
 startMonitorMem();

 /** USE CASE STARTS HERE **/

 MemPlay *pCorruptMem = new MemPlay();
 pCorruptMem->MyMemPlay();

 DumpMemory *pSafeMem = new DumpMemory();
 pSafeMem->MyDumpMemory();

 /*** USE CASE ENDS HERE **/

 while(1)
 {

 }


 return 0;
}
```

Here is the output -

```html
 <<< a lot of strCpy calls >>>
Strcpy done
Strcpy Started
Strcpy done
Strcpy Started
Strcpy done
Strcpy Started
Strcpy done
Strcpy Started
Strcpy done
Strcpy Started
Strcpy done
Strcpy Started
Strcpy done
Strcpy Started
Strcpy done
*** glibc detected *** ./prog.out: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0999a050 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x4bfc99f2]
/lib/libc.so.6[0x4bfcbad2]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x65)[0x4bfcde75]
./prog.out(_Znwj+0x22)[0x8049130]
./prog.out(main+0x36)[0x80494e0]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x4bf6a6b3]
./prog.out[0x8048da1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 31854551   /export/home/joshis1/Eclipse_WorkSpace1/memory_tool_hook/src/prog.out
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 31854551   /export/home/joshis1/Eclipse_WorkSpace1/memory_tool_hook/src/prog.out
0804b000-0804d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0999a000-099bf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
4bf28000-4bf49000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 41030167   /lib/ld-2.14.90.so
4bf49000-4bf4a000 r--p 00020000 fd:00 41030167   /lib/ld-2.14.90.so
4bf4a000-4bf4b000 rw-p 00021000 fd:00 41030167   /lib/ld-2.14.90.so
4bf51000-4c0fb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 41030168   /lib/libc-2.14.90.so
4c0fb000-4c0fc000 ---p 001aa000 fd:00 41030168   /lib/libc-2.14.90.so
4c0fc000-4c0fe000 r--p 001aa000 fd:00 41030168   /lib/libc-2.14.90.so
4c0fe000-4c0ff000 rw-p 001ac000 fd:00 41030168   /lib/libc-2.14.90.so
4c0ff000-4c102000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
4c104000-4c12d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 41030181   /lib/libm-2.14.90.so
4c12d000-4c12e000 r--p 00028000 fd:00 41030181   /lib/libm-2.14.90.so
4c12e000-4c12f000 rw-p 00029000 fd:00 41030181   /lib/libm-2.14.90.so
4c161000-4c17d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 41030182   /lib/libgcc_s-4.6.3-20120306.so.1
4c17d000-4c17e000 rw-p 0001b000 fd:00 41030182   /lib/libgcc_s-4.6.3-20120306.so.1
4c4d1000-4c5b3000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 48761002   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
4c5b3000-4c5b7000 r--p 000e1000 fd:00 48761002   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
4c5b7000-4c5b9000 rw-p 000e5000 fd:00 48761002   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
4c5b9000-4c5bf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76fa000-b76fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7728000-b772b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b772b000-b772c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
bf9e9000-bfacd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I got the answer. I cannot use Ofstream here. I should use C based fopen and fprintf. The fopen and frprintf doesn't use new(). Thus, it will work here.
Here is my code, which is good now.

```html
/** Headers needed for the tool **/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include  <execinfo.h>
#include  <cxxabi.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

/** timer check **/
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
/** timer checks ends here **/

/*************NEED EXTRA MONITORING ************************/
#define TIME_STAMPING (1)
#define MEMORY_LEAK_MONITORING (1)
/***********************************************************/

/*** USE CASE HEADERS ***/
#include "memOperation.h"
#include  "DumpMemory.h"
/*** USE CASE HEADERS ENDS ***/


/** Buffer for adding Pattern - Signature **/
#define BUFFER (4)

/*** Array Assume-- map of pointers and size  *********/
struct pointerBlkSizeInfo
{
 unsigned long int m_PointerAddress;
 unsigned long int m_blkSize;
 int reportedFaulty;
};


/*** String for File Name path ***/
const char *FileName = "/export/home/joshis1/DBG_REC.log";

/*** DUMP Corrupted Memory details **/
const char *FileCorruptDetails = "/export/home/joshis1/DBG_CORRUPT.log";


/** Log files to record **/
FILE  *dumpfile;
FILE *corruptMemFile;

/**** Maintain array of pointerBlkSizeInfo **/
#define MONITOR_MEM_SIZE  (1024)
/**** Map created **************************/
pointerBlkSizeInfo ptrSizeMap[MONITOR_MEM_SIZE];

/*** Prototype *********/
static void startMonitorMem();
/*****************Prototype ends here **/


/**********Prints the caller needs rdynamic***********************/
static void printCaller( unsigned long int memPointerRec )
{
 void *array[ 50 ];
 int size = backtrace( array, 50 );
 char **messages = backtrace_symbols( array, size );

 /* skip first and second stack frame (points here) */
 for ( int frame = 0; frame < size  && messages != NULL; ++frame )
 {
  char *mangled_name = 0, *offset_begin = 0, *offset_end = 0;

  /* find parantheses and +address offset surrounding mangled name */
  for ( char *msg = messages[frame]; *msg; ++msg )
  {
   if ( *msg == '(' )
   {
    mangled_name = msg;
   }
   else if ( *msg == '+' )
   {
    offset_begin = msg;
   }
   else if ( *msg == ')' )
   {
    offset_end = msg;
    break;
   }
  }

  /* if the line could be processed, attempt to demangle the symbol */
  if ( mangled_name && offset_begin && offset_end &&
    mangled_name < offset_begin )
  {
   *mangled_name++ = '\0';
   *offset_begin++ = '\0';
   *offset_end++ = '\0';

   int status;
   char * real_name = abi::__cxa_demangle(mangled_name, 0, 0, &status);

   /* if demangling is successful, output the demangled function name */
   if ( status == 0 )
   {
    fprintf(dumpfile,"demangled name %s\r\n",real_name);
    fflush(dumpfile);
   }
   else
   {
    fprintf(dumpfile,"mangled name %s\r\n",real_name);
    fflush(dumpfile);
   }
   free( real_name );
  }
 }
 free( messages );

 struct mallinfo freeblockAvailable;

 freeblockAvailable = mallinfo();

 fprintf(dumpfile,"Avail free bytes = %lu\r\n",freeblockAvailable.fordblks);
 fflush(dumpfile);
}

/** Overloaded new Operator **/
void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
 unsigned int index = 0;

#ifdef TIME_STAMPING
 struct timeval ts;

#endif

 char buff[4] = "ACE";

#ifdef TIME_STAMPING
 gettimeofday (&ts, NULL);
#endif

 void *mem = std::malloc(sz + BUFFER );
 std::cout<<"Strcpy Started"<<std::endl;
 strncpy((char *)((unsigned long int )mem + sz),buff,4);
 std::cout<<"Strcpy done"<<std::endl;


 unsigned long int memPointerRec = (unsigned long int)mem;

 for(index = 0; index <= MONITOR_MEM_SIZE; index++ )
 {
  if( ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress == 0 )
  {
   ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress =  ( unsigned long int)mem;
   ptrSizeMap[index].m_blkSize = sz;
#ifdef TIME_STAMPING
   fprintf(dumpfile,"Ptr alloc = %lu , Time = %d.%ds , PID = %5d \r\n",ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress,(int)(ts.tv_sec)%10000, (int)ts.tv_usec/1000,getpid());
#else
   fprintf(dumpfile,"Ptr alloc = %lu \r\n",ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress);
#endif
   fflush(dumpfile);
   printCaller(ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress);
   break;
  }
 }

 if(index  > MONITOR_MEM_SIZE )
 {
  std::cout<<"MemoryTool..MapSize Increase"<<std::endl;
 }

 return mem;
}

/** Overloaded free Operator **/
void operator delete(void* ptr)
{
 std::free(ptr);

 for(unsigned int index = 0; index <= MONITOR_MEM_SIZE; index++ )
 {
  if( ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress == (unsigned long int)ptr )
  {
   ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress =  0;
   ptrSizeMap[index].m_blkSize = 0;
   break;
  }
 }
}


/**************Memory Monitor Routine--Every 10 seconds executes *******************************/
void monitorMem (int temp)
{
 struct itimerval tout_val;

#ifdef TIME_STAMPING
 struct timeval ts;
 gettimeofday (&ts, NULL);
#endif

 std::cout<<"Monitoring Memory!!!"<<std::endl;
 tout_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
 tout_val.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
 tout_val.it_value.tv_sec = 10; /* 10 seconds timer */
 tout_val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

 /**** check if the memory buffer overflow occurred or not **/

 for(unsigned int index = 0; index <= MONITOR_MEM_SIZE; index++ )
 {
  if (ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress != 0 )
  {
   const char *temp = (char *) (ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress + ptrSizeMap[index].m_blkSize);

   if(strncmp(temp,"ACE",3) == 0 )
   {
    /** Matched **/
   }
   else
   {
    /** Un -Matched ***/
    if(ptrSizeMap[index].reportedFaulty == 0 )
    {
     /** reported not **/
     ptrSizeMap[index].reportedFaulty = 1;
#ifdef TIME_STAMPING
     fprintf(corruptMemFile,"Pointer corrupted =  = %lu and size = %lu , Time = %d.%ds , PID = %5d \r\n",ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress,ptrSizeMap[index].m_blkSize,(int)(ts.tv_sec)%10000, (int)ts.tv_usec/1000,getpid());
#else
     fprintf(corruptMemFile,"Pointer corrupted =  = %lu and size = %lu \r\n",ptrSizeMap[index].m_PointerAddress,ptrSizeMap[index].m_blkSize );
#endif
     fflush(corruptMemFile);
     std::cout<<"Shreyas..the memory is corrupted"<<std::endl;
    }
   }
  }

 }

 /** Monitor Mem Status for Memory Leaks -- can disable this **/
#if defined (MEMORY_LEAK_MONITORING) && defined (TIME_STAMPING)

 struct mallinfo freeblockAvailable;
 freeblockAvailable = mallinfo();
 fprintf(corruptMemFile,"Avail free bytes = %lu, Time = %d.%ds , PID = %5d\r\n",freeblockAvailable.fordblks,(int)(ts.tv_sec)%10000, (int)ts.tv_usec/1000,getpid());
 fflush(corruptMemFile);

#elif MEMORY_LEAK_MONITORING
     struct mallinfo freeblockAvailable;
  freeblockAvailable = mallinfo();
  fprintf(corruptMemFile,"Avail free bytes = %lu\r\n",freeblockAvailable.fordblks);
  fflush(corruptMemFile);
#endif



 signal(SIGALRM,monitorMem);
 setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tout_val,0);

}

/*** Start Monitoring the Mem -- Timer Initialization ***/
static void startMonitorMem()
{
 /** initialize the memory lookup map to zero **/
 memset(&ptrSizeMap,0,sizeof(pointerBlkSizeInfo)*MONITOR_MEM_SIZE);

 dumpfile = fopen(FileName,"w");
 corruptMemFile = fopen(FileCorruptDetails,"w");

 /** initialize the memory lookup map to zero **/
 memset(&ptrSizeMap,0,sizeof(pointerBlkSizeInfo)*MONITOR_MEM_SIZE);

 struct itimerval tout_val;
 tout_val.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
 tout_val.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
 tout_val.it_value.tv_sec = 10; /* 10 seconds timer */
 tout_val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
 setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tout_val,0);
 signal(SIGALRM,monitorMem); /* set the Alarm signal capture */
}



/********************Main routine ************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 /** Install the memory monitoring now **/
 startMonitorMem();

 /** USE CASE STARTS HERE **/

 MemPlay *pCorruptMem = new MemPlay();
 pCorruptMem->MyMemPlay();

 DumpMemory *pSafeMem = new DumpMemory();
 pSafeMem->MyDumpMemory();

 /** delete the memory now **/
 //pCorruptMem->clearMem();

 /*** USE CASE ENDS HERE **/

 while(1)
 {

 }


 return 0;
}
```